# Please check my approximation . $~\frac{a+b}{b-a}=\frac{2a+b-a}{b-a}\approx\frac{2a}{b-a}$

Tags: approximation

$$  \left( a,b \in \mathbb R_{> 0} \right) ~~\wedge~~ \left( a < b\right) ~~\wedge~~ \left( \left( b-a \right) \ll a \right)  $$

I want to derive the below appoximation equation .

$$  \frac{  a+b }{ b-a   } =\frac{  2a+b-a  }{  b-a  } \approx \frac{  2a  }{ b-a   }   $$

What I tried to derive it are as below .

$$ \frac{  a+b }{ b-a   } =\frac{  2a+b-a  }{  b-a  }  $$

$$ = \frac{  2 a }{ b-a   } + \frac{  b-a  }{ b-a   }  $$

$$ = 2 \underbrace{\left( \frac{  a  }{ b-a   }  \right)}_\text{very large} +1 $$

$$ \approx \frac{  2a   }{ b-a   } ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Previous 1 in the previous eqn is trifiling so it was removed}  $$

Is this derivation right?

Comment: Well, what does $\approx$ mean here?  That is, what range are you considering?  If $b=0$ and $a\neq 0$ you are claiming that $-1\approx -2$.

Comment: The symbol b takes  a positive real number .

Comment: So take $b=10^{-1000}$.  It's just not clear what you are claiming.

Comment: More to the point, why bother with this "approximation"?  You could, more accurately, just say that $\frac {a+b}{b-a}=\frac {2a}{b-a}+1$.

Comment: I just copied the below as same as written in the textbook .
$$  \frac{  a+b }{ b-a   } =\frac{  2a+b-a  }{  b-a  } \approx \frac{  2a  }{ b-a   }   $$

Comment: More strictly , $~\approx~$ was not used in the book , $~\fallingdotseq$ is used in it .

Comment: The two expressions differ by $1$.  It some contexts, that might be negligible, in others it wouldn't be. There is no universal notion of "negligible".

Comment: I see .

This approximation was used in the problem of iron core in electrical engineering .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always depends on what you mean by '$\approx$'. Your expression $$\frac{  a+b }{ b-a   } \approx \frac{  2a  }{ b-a   }$$ could be interpreted as what is called asymptotically equivalent. A function $f$ is called asymptotically equivalent to another function $g$ if $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1.$$ This would mean in your case $$\frac{  \frac{  a+b }{ b-a   } }{ \frac{  2a  }{ b-a   } }=\frac{  a+b }{ 2a }=\frac{1 }{2}\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right),$$ that $b/a$ should be approximately $1$ or in other words that $a$ and $b$ should be approximately the same.